# Parking lot problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm facing some difficulties in this question:

The probability of a person arrive to a parking lot before 8:00 am is 0.4, the probability to find a place to park given that she arrived before 8:00am is 0.6. If she get after 8:00 am, the probability to find a place to park is 0.3.

Given that the person, in 3 days, arrived exactly 2 days before 8:00 am, what is the probability that she successfully parked at least 1 day.

I tried different approaches, but in each of those I got a different result.

I tried to define: X: Number of days that she successfully parkedP(X>=1) = $1-P(X=0)$ = and I got $0.66$, but when I try to do P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3) i got $0.875$ . I don't know what I'm missing.

I tried:$1-P(X=0) = 1 - \binom{3}{1}$ *P(not park in a day | arrived to the parking lot before 8:00) * P(not park in a day | arrived to the parking lot before 8:00) * P(not park in a day | arrived to the parking lot after 8:00)

= $1 - 3*0.4*0.4*0.7 = 1 - 0.336 = 0.664$

The second approach was thinking that if I know that the person arrives 2 days before 8:00 and 1 day after 8:00, so now the probability of arrive to a parking lot in 3 days before 8:00 is $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ before 8:00. And I did $1 - P(Not Park)^3 = 1 - .5^3 = 0.875$

Comment: Where does the number $.5$ come from in your second approach?

Comment: I don't agree with either answer.  The probability does not depend on which day she shows up late, so lets say that's the third day.  The probability that she fails on each day is then $.4\times .4\times .7=.112$ so the answer is $.888$

Comment: I did P(Park) = P(Arrive<8 and Park) + P(Arrive>8 and park) = $\frac{2}{3} * .6 + \frac{1}{3}*.2

Comment: As a sanity check:  ignore the day she comes in late.  The probability of failing on the two days she is early is $.4^2=.16$, so the probability that she gets a space at least once is $.84$  Clearly, adding the third day can not lower that.

Comment: While it is unnecessary, even if you applied conditional probability formula, you will get to the same answer.

Comment: @lulu You are right, thank you. Now it makes sense for me.

Comment: @MathLover, I thought about it, but I ended messing up , can you explain more how to do it using the conditional formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality: the person arrived before 8am on the 1st two days
and after 8am on the 3rd day.

When the person arrives before 8am, p(failure) = 0.4. 
When the person arrives after 8am, p(failure) = 0.7.

Therefore, chance of 3 consecutive failures if $(0.4)^2 \times 0.7$.

Then chance of success is $1 - $ chance of 3 consecutive failures.

---

The probability is given that the chance of a person arriving  before 8am is $(0.4)$.  Because you are given that the person arrived before 8am on exactly 2 of the 3 days, the probability equaling $(0.4)$ may reasonably be
construed to be a **red herring**.

If you had **not** been given the information that the person arrived before 8am on exactly 2 of the 3 days, then the problem would have been significantly more complicated.

You would then have had to reason that the chance of there being no parking space on 1 specific day is

$$[(0.4) \times (0.4)] + [(0.6) \times (0.7)].$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you should look at it:

If $X$ is the event of she finding parking space,

$P (X = 0) =  (1- 0.6)^2 \times (1-0.3)$

So the probability that she gets parking at least one of the days

$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X=0)$

Even if you want to apply conditional probability formula, here is how you may want to look at it.

Even B: Probability that she reaches exactly two days before 8 AM
Event A: She does not find parking space any of the days

$P(B) = \displaystyle {3 \choose 2} \times 0.4^2 \times (1-0.4)$

$P(A \cap B) = \displaystyle {3 \choose 2} \times (0.4 \times 0.4)^2 \times (0.6 \times 0.7)$

So $P(A|B) = 0.4^2 \times 0.7$

What you are interested in is $ \ 1 - P(A|B)$